# Fivestar widget default on new comment field?

Tags: 7, rating

The Comment View admin panel allows me to set which of the Fivestar widget styles to use as the default to display for ratings in comments on a particular node, but the "new comment" form seems to not pick up that preference. Where can I set the display style for the "new comment" form field when it's being auto-inserted into a node?

Is this a bug in Fivestar that I should report (or a feature request to allow this customization)?

Comment: But is there any Fivestar widget for the "new comment" form?! Doesn't make sense to me, rating a form field. Am I missing something?

Comment: For a custom Node Content-Type, I added a Field to the Comment object for that Node, setting it to a Fivestar field. Therefore it gets added to the display of existing Comments for that Node, and to the "Add New Comment" form for that Node.

Comment: To clarify, the Fivestar widget in the "new comment" form is tied to the Node the comment is going to be attached to; the user is rating the node, not the form field itself.